# How to convert Django uploadedfile.InMemory into numpy array or Image

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-requests, http-post

#Views.py-- I want to convert uploaded image file into numpy array(cv2.imread)

```py
def upload(request):
  if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['image_file']:
    f = request.FILES['image_file']
    myfile = str(f.read())
    array_np = cv2.imread(myfile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the byte into int and decode it using `cv2.imdecode`. Then you will get a cv2 image array.

```
image = cv2.imdecode(numpy.frombuffer(myfile , numpy.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```